# retrive primary_key of just inserted data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I just added the data in mysql with CI query builder. Now I need to retrive the primary key(Track Code) of those data(row). I used insert and select query simultanously but it didn't worked.

Model:

```
public function complainReg($cName,$vName,$Email,$Contact,$date,$Complain,$ip)
        {
            $data = array(
                'cName' => $cName,
                'vName' => $vName,
                'Email' => $Email, 
                'Contact' => $Contact,
                'Date' => $date,
                'Complain' => $Complain,
                'ip' => $ip
                );
            $sql= $this->db->set($data)->get_compiled_insert('tbl_complain');
            $q=$this->db->query($sql);
            return $q;
        }
```

Controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) 
        {
            $cName=$this->input->post('cName');
            $vName=$this->input->post('vName');
            $Email=$this->input->post('email');
            $Contact=$this->input->post('phone');
            $date=$this->input->post('Date');
            $Complain=$this->input->post('complain');
            $ip=file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
            $this->HamroSamajModel->complainReg($cName,$vName,$Email,$Contact,$date,$Complain,$ip);
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message","Your complain has been registered sucessfully");
        }
        $this->load->view('Complain/index');
    }
```

Comment: primary key means ID ?

Comment: Yeah ID that I use to insert the data...after recording the data I wan't to show the primary key on page as a tracking code.

Comment: check below answer added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need last Insert ID just try this

```
public function complainReg($cName,$vName,$Email,$Contact,$date,$Complain,$ip)
{
    $data = array(
        'cName' => $cName,
        'vName' => $vName,
        'Email' => $Email, 
        'Contact' => $Contact,
        'Date' => $date,
        'Complain' => $Complain,
        'ip' => $ip
    );

    $this->db->insert('tbl_complain', $data);
    $lastID = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $lastID;
}
```